# 3Dimensional runge kutta and Euler method ( help to verify the idea and proposition)

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

Previously,i been discussing this idea with a tutor for sometime. However it turn out that the proof is not comprehensible.But now the derivation for the accuracy up to $O(h^2)$ can be understood. However, the derivation for accuracy $O(h^3)$ will require the use of eq 1.6 that i view it as a fail. is there any other way i can derive accuracy $O(h^3)$ without using eq 1.6?

The detail can be found at the link below.

http://www.docdroid.net/161p6/curve.pdf.html

For the 3D curve, we choose

$g=u_pf+u_v$ where $f=-\frac{k_v}{k_p}$

the solution of $p_1$ that satisfy the equation $u(p_1,v_0+h)-
u(p_0,v_0)=g(p_0,v_0)h$ can  expand using taylor expansion and consider the coefficient of h equal to $g(p_0,v_0)$ while coefficient of $h^n$ where $n>1$ equal to $0$

$u_p(p_1-p_0)-u_v(h)+\frac{1}{2}[u_{pp}(p_1-p_0)^2+2u_{pv}(p_1-p_0)h+u_{vv}h^2]+...=g(p_0,v_0)h$

By considering again $p_1=p_0+a$

The coefficient of h must be $g(p_0,v_0)$

$u_p(a)+u_v(h)=(u_pf+f_v)h$

which found $a=hf$

The value of a is next substitute to the 2nd order taylor series 
$\frac{1}{2}[u_{pp}(a)^2+2u_{pv}(a)h+u_{vv}h^2]$ by assuming the sum of this 2nd order taylor expansion is not zero, then there must be a term b in front of a and let $p_1=p_0+a+b$ such that

$u_p(b)+\frac{1}{2}[u_{pp}(a)^2+2u_{pv}(a)h+u_{vv}h^2]=0$

so $b=-\frac{h^2}{2}[\frac{u_{pp}f^2+2u_{pv}f+u_{vv}}{u_p}]$

So by solving this equation

$u(p_1,v_0+h)-u(p_0,v_0)=g(p_0,v_0)h$

which $p_0,h,v_0$ is know it produce the solution of

$p_1=p_0+hf+-\frac{h^2}{2}[\frac{u_{pp}f^2+2u_{pv}f+u_{vv}}{u_p}]+O(h^3)$

while solving the equation

$k(p_{exact},v_0+h)-k(p_0,v_0)=0$

$p_{exact}=p_0+hf+\frac{h^2}{2}(f_pf+f_v)+O(h^3)$

Noticed that $p_1$ contain the properties of tangent to the curve $p_{exact}$ at point $(p_0,v_0)$
However when one reduce the value of h to be very small the value of $p_1$ for both equation reduce to an "Euler method"

$p_1 \approx p_{exact} \approx p_0+hf$

In order to obtain the exact solution of the DE for the 3D curve, we can consider $p(v_0+h)=p(v_0)+hf+\frac{h^2}{2}(f_pf+f_v)+...$ and find what is $u(p(v_0+h),v_0)-u(p_0,v_0)$ assuming $p(v_0)=p_0$

$u(p(v_0+h),v_0)-u(p_0,v_0)$

$=u_p(p(v_0+h)-p_0)+u_v(h)+\frac{1}{2}[u_{pp}(p(v_0+h)-p_0)^2+2u_{pv}(p(v_0+h))(h)+u_{vv}(h^2)+...]$

$=h(u_pf+u_v)+\frac{h^2}{2}[u_pf_pf+u_{pp}f^2+2u_{pv}f+u_pf_v+u_{pp}]+...$

which show formula resemble the Taylor expansion of the solution of differential equation $\frac{dp}{dv} = f(v,p)$ with initial conditions $v = v_0$ and $p = p_0$

while $u_(p_1,v_0+h)-u_(p_0,v_0)=g(p_0,v_0)h$ is analogous to an Euler method as only the 1st term will be the same.

The numerical scheme of "Euler method" of such function is as below

$u(p_0,v_0)+g(p_0,v_0)h=u(p_1,v_0+h)$

$p_1=p_0+hf+O(h^2)$ where $O(h^2)$ is indeterminable and varies with different function of u

The Midpoint method for single step will be

$u(p_0,v_0)+0.5g(p_0,v_0)h+0.5g(p_1,v_0+h)h=u(p_2,v_0+h)$

$p_2=p_0+hf+\frac{h^2}{2}(f_pf+f_v)+O(h^3)$ where $O(h^3)$ is indeterminable and varies with different function of u

The similar RK3 scheme will be

$u(p_0,v_0)+xg(p_0,v_0)h+yg(p_0+ahf,v_0+bh)h+z(p_0+c(hf+\frac{h^2}{2}(f_pf+f_v)+O(h^3),v_0+dh)h=u(p_3,v_0+h)$

the term $p_1$ obtain from previous formula cannot be applied into the formula $yg(p_0+ahf,v_0+bh)h$ as$ p_1=p_0+hf+O(h^2)$ and $O(h^2)$ is indeterminable. It will require the use of Euler method to find it where $p_1=p_0+hf$ otherwise it introduce error of $O(h^3)$ into the scheme which is indeterminable.

The term $hf+\frac{h^2}{2}(f_pf+f_v)+O(h^3)$ can be obtain using previous value of $p_2-p_0$

After rearrange the term get the equations

$x+y+z=1$

$ya+zc=0.5$

$yb+zd=0.5$

$zc=\frac{1}{3}$

$ya^2+zc^2=\frac{1}{3}$

$yab+zdc=\frac{1}{3}$

$yb^2+zd^2=\frac{1}{3}$

\begin{align*}
x & = \frac{12d^2 - 15d + 4}{12d(d - 1)}, \\
y & = \frac{- 1}{12(d - 1)}, \\
z & = \frac{1}{3d},\\
a & =  - 2(d - 1), \\
b & =  - 2(d - 1),\\
c & = d.
\end{align*}

The solution as below with d=1 or 0 no solution. So choose d=0.5

Obtain similar RK3

$u(p_0,v_0)+\frac{1}{6}g(p_0,v_0)h+\frac{1}{6}g(p_0+hf,v_0+h)h+\frac{2}{3}(p_0+0.5(p_2-p_0),v_0+0.5h)h=u(p_3,v_0+h)$

The purpose of this scheme is not to solve ODE but to give an infinite variety of choices of u and g such that the scheme produce almost the same numerical result since it is referring to particular solution of a DE.

Here are just some example

$u(p,v)=P^Av^B, \frac{du}{dv}=g(p,v)=(B-1.4A)P^AV^{B-1} $ The directional derivative according to formula 2.2 is $\frac{dp}{dv}=-1.4\frac{P}{V}$

choosing arbitrary constant A=2 B=1.5

Exact solution of $\frac{dp}{dv}=-1.4\frac{p}{v}$ at $v_0+h$ assume initial condition $(p_0,v_0)=(1,1)$ and h=0.5 is $p_{exact}=\frac{1}{1.5^{1.4}}=0.56685$

The numerical scheme of "Euler method" of such function is as below

$u(p_0,v_0)+g(p_0,v_0)h=u(p_1,v_0+h)$

$u(1,1)+g(1,1)(0.5)=u(p_1,1.5)$

$(1)^2(1)^{1.5}-1.3(1)^2(1)^{0.5}(0.5)=p_1(1+0.5)^{1.5}$

By solving the equation
$p_1=0.4346$

This value is substitute to similar midpoint method
$u(p_0,v_0)+0.5g(p_0,v_0)0.5+0.5g(p_1,v_0+0.5)=u(p_2,v_0+0.5)$

Obtain
$p_2=0.533735$

Using similar RK3 scheme
$u(p_0,v_0)+\frac{1}{6}g(p_0,v_0)h+\frac{1}{6}g(p_0+hf,v_0+h)h+\frac{2}{3}(p_0+0.5(p_2-p_0),v_0+0.5h)=u(p_3,v_0+h)$

Obtain $P_3=0.5689$

The exact solution is 0.56685 so the similar RK3 have reduce the error compare to midpoint and $p_3=p_0+hf+\frac{h^2}{2}(f_pf+f_v)+\frac{h^3}{6}(f_pf+f_v)_pf+(f_pf+f_v)_v+O(h^4)$

If construct $\frac{dp}{dv}=-1.4\frac{P}{V}$ using u=2.5PV and $\frac{du}{dv}=g(p,v)=-P$, assume condition (1,1) as well and approximate $P(v_0+0.5)$

Then the 1st step will be

$2.5(1)(1)-(1)(0.5)=2.5P_2(1.5)$

$p_1=0.5333$

Using value of $p_1$ in the above midpoint formula obtain

$p_2=0.56444$

Using similar RK3 above obtained

$p_3=0.56825$

Which error is smaller compare to $p_2$

This show the possibilities of construct exactly the same curve using infinitely many different function of u and g.

Comment: TL:DR.  Maybe try posting several times specific questions you have about it.

Comment: Would it not be easier to use one Euler step as a predictor of the next curve point and Newton's method on the curve defining equations as a corrector? See also more general path-following and homotopy schemes.